# Cannot use right the inheritance in PHP class

Tags: php, sql, inheritance, constructor

I have this parent class in PHP:

```
 class parentClass{
    public $table;

    public function __construct(){
       $this->table = "my_parent_table";
    }

    public function getName($id) {
      $strQuery = "SELECT name FROM $this->table WHERE id=$id";

      $result = mysql_query($strQuery);
      if ($result) {
         $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
         if ($row) {
             return $row->name;
          } else {
             return false;
          }
      } else {      
         return false;
      }
    } 
 }
```

And I have also another class with inherits this one:

```
 class childClass extends parentClass{
     public $table;

     public function __construct(){
       $this->table = "my_child_table";
     }
 }
```

Then in another file I am doing:

```
 $myObj = new childClass();
 $name = $myObj->getName('1');
```

The problem now is that the getName function has a null table, so the variable $this->table is null, while I want it to be ""my_child_table" as long as I have a childClass object.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: put `var_dump($this->table);` in the beginning of `getName` and show the result here

Comment: ok my fault, the variable $table was private, so this was the problem,I changed it to public and works fine.

Comment: Set it to `protected` if you don't want it to be publicly accessible yet still overridable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but this look tricky:

```
class childClass extends parentClass{
     public $table;
```

The `parentClass` already defines a `$table`, so it's likely that redeclaring it inside the child class will clobber the parent's version. You have to remove the declaration here. Also, public visibility doesn't really encapsulate the state very well; use `protected` in the parent instead.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
```

You should add `parent::__construct()` here (unless parent only sets `$this->table`, but even then it's good to add)

```
        $this->table = "my_child_table";
    }
}
```